# Can the wearer of power and light armors benefit from two force fields?

Tags: armor, starfinder

Although one suit of armor cannot support more than one force field upgrade, light armor can be worn underneath power armor.

Can force fields be installed in *both* the light armor *and* the power armor so that the wearer can benefit from *two* force fields?

Comment: Not a duplicate this is specically for wearing light armor under power armor and installing a force field in both

Comment: Edited this; I hope that's okay. If the question's not asking what you want answered, please edit it further or roll it back.

Comment: To me, this is a subset of the other question

Comment: No the other question simply asks whether or not you can wear multiple armors for the upgrade slots since it is not stated anywhere but it is stated that you can wear light armor under power armor

Comment: Light armor can explicitly worn *and have an effect* while in power armor, while the same is not true for second skin armor, so this question has a different answer from the other.

Comment: If it's edited to be more clear that it's a question of light armor vs second skin armor, I could see that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are not supposed to be able to use upgrades on your light armor while in power armor, after all your jet pack on your light armor allowing you to fly while in your colossal war-mech is just plain silly. But, as far as I know this hasn't actually been addressed in the rules. However, I would definitely rule that all upgrades on light armor are non-functional in power armor and, for that matter, upgrades on an Android (again jet packs), etc. 
Additionally, let's say you can wear both force fields, then we can take a page from classic D&D and Pathfinder, you could have both but they don't stack, after all in Pathfinder two false life spells wouldn't stack. It's pretty clear that multiple force fields is not intended by the game design.